# display current month until the 15th day, then to next month after the 15th day. E.g: If July 10 - display “July”, If July 20 - display “August”,

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've written script for both **current month** & **following month** (shown below). However, I am trying to achieve something in the middle; displaying the current month until the 15th day, then changing to next month after the 15th day.

Example:
If today is July 10th, display “July”.
If today is July 20th, display “August”.

**Displaying the Current Month, alternating: “var n = month[d.getMonth()];”**

```js
{
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var d = new Date();
  var n = month[d.getMonth()]; 

    document.write (month = n)
}
```

**Displaying the Following Month, alternating: “var n = month[d.getMonth()+1];”**

```js
{
  var month = new Array();
  month[0] = "January";
  month[1] = "February";
  month[2] = "March";
  month[3] = "April";
  month[4] = "May";
  month[5] = "June";
  month[6] = "July";
  month[7] = "August";
  month[8] = "September";
  month[9] = "October";
  month[10] = "November";
  month[11] = "December";

  var d = new Date();
  var n = month[d.getMonth()+1]; 

    document.write (month = n)
}
```

I've experimented with values in between the 0-1, but still no luck. I haven't managed to find a solution after a lot of research so any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ryan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the day of the month with `new Date().getDate()`. Then, if it is more than 15, add 1 to the month index to return.

Also, I rewrote your months array in a simple form instead of `month[0] = "January";`

```js
{
  var month = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"]

  var d = new Date();
  var dayOfMonth = d.getDate();
  var n = month[ d.getMonth() + (dayOfMonth > 15 ? 1 : 0) ]; 

    document.write ("month = " + n)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a function to return the month name from the month, and a function to get the next month.

Then, if the current day is 15 or greater, we'll show the next month:

```js
function getMonthName(month, locales = 'default') {
    return new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), month, 1).toLocaleString(locales, { month: 'long'} );
}

function getNextMonth(month) {
    return (month + 1) % 12;
}

function getMonthToDisplay(date) {
    let month = date.getMonth();
    if (date.getDate() >= 15) { 
        month = getNextMonth(month);
    }
    return getMonthName(month);
  
}

let dates = ["2021-06-14T18:00:00Z","2021-06-15T00:00:00Z", "2021-09-30T00:00:00Z", "1965-11-01T15:00:00Z"].map(dt => new Date(dt));
for(let d of dates) {
    console.log("Date:", d.toDateString(), "Current:", getMonthName(d.getMonth()), "Display:", getMonthToDisplay(d))
}

console.log("Testing all days in June 2021...");
dates = [...Array(30).keys()].map((v,k) => new Date(2021, 5, k + 1));
for(let d of dates) {
    console.log("Date:", d.toDateString(), "Current:", getMonthName(d.getMonth()), "Display:", getMonthToDisplay(d))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get

```
date -> new Date().getDate()
month -> new Date().getMonth()
```

and compare date with `15` and get the desired result.

```js
var month = new Array();
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

const now = new Date();
const mon = now.getMonth();
const date = now.getDate();

const result = date > 15 ? month[mon + 1] : month[mon];

console.log(result);
document.write(result)
```